# log4j does not create a log file in the system

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, log4j

I am creating a Spring Boot Application in STS (Spring Tool Suite).

The problem occurs when trying to log using log4j. It does not create the log file in the system, though it does log on the console. I tried various methods given in the forum(including checking case-sensitivity, , but I think I am going wrong somewhere. An elaborate response would be really helpful.

I have a dependency in the **pom.xml** file for the log4j jar:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

In my **log4j.properties** file, I am trying to have logs in console as well as a file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log4j.log
log4j.appender.file.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Java controller where I want to log (**IndexController.java**)

```
package com.project.Controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IndexController.class.getName());

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String index(Model model) {

        logger.info("in index");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Please comment if you need any further details. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dependency for `spring-boot-starter-log4j` and exclude `spring-boot-starter-logging` in your pom.xml.Make the following entry in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This should create the log file and log the details.

Comment: Remove the dependency for log4j which you had earlier added.

Comment: Trying to log directly to `C:` may also be a problem.